# Calcultate dimensions of mesh using vertex and face data

Tags: math, opengl-es, 3d, computational-geometry

I have 3d models made in Blender. I need to load them for further rendering using OpenGL ES.
I also want to implement picking, so I need to know object dimensions. So far I did not find option like "export dimensions" while exportiong to wavefront obj in Blender. I decided to calculate them manually.

**So, I have vertex and face data. How do I calculate object dimensions?** It may be done roughly, whatever. Or maybe I'm on the wrong tracK?

Comment: 'Dimensions' are a bit imprecise, Blender have its own units, and also supports metric system (maybe more, i'm not sure). I've seen .obj export changing scale when importing in another software, so its dimensions were kinda off all the time. Is there a defined unit for your dimensions ?
Also, isn't there any function / object property in Blender that'll give you the object dimensions ?

Comment: @Kotch The obj format does not specify units, that it is set by whatever program you are using to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just the minimum and maximum coordinate value found for each vertex for each of the X, Y and Z axes?

Comment: +1 If all you have is vertices/face data, that is indeed the only way to do it.